# Import single lodash functions for libraries with aot

Tags: angular, lodash, angular5, angular2-aot, aot

I'm trying to use lodash with the syntax "import * as includes from 'lodash.includes';" so i don't need to install all lodash library and just the functions that I need. Everything works fine but aot. I build my library to use it in other project as a node_modules and when I do ng serve everything works fine but when doing ng serve --aot I got: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash.includes' in etc...".
I could solve the problem by installing lodash in my library project and use it with the syntax "import * as _ from 'lodash';" but I'd like to have only the dependencies that I need not the whole lodash library.
Any guess?

Comment: Did my answer end up working for you? If not, then let me know and I will do my best to correct it and help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to include the entire Lodash library in your Angular project, then you need to use the [`lodash-es`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) library as a dependency instead of the normal `lodash` library as a dependency. Just change it in your `package.json` file and then in each of your references within your project to point to that library instead.