# How to use lodash function in angular 5 project?

Tags: typescript, lodash

I want to use merge function from lodash. If I am including whole lodash , it increases bundle size . So I am trying to use function from lodash. But it is giving error.

```
import { merge } from 'lodash/merge';
```

or

```
  import merge from 'lodash/merge';
```

Can anyone suggest me how to use this in angular 5 application ?
I have installed following versions:

```
 "lodash": "^4.17.5",
  "@types/lodash": "^4.14.104"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import single lodash functions for libraries with aot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297734/import-single-lodash-functions-for-libraries-with-aot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

import * as merge from 'lodash/fp/merge'; worked fine

Comment: click the 'checkmark' (under the # of votes) on your answer above to mark as answered

Answer (score 1):

You can still do any JS way of things in TS (since it's a super-set)

Try with:

```
import merge = require('lodash/merge');
```

Comment: import * as merge from 'lodash/fp/merge'; worked fine

Comment: @Shikha well, you can add that as self answer so other can refer

Comment: @Shikha I didn't get why you accepted this? Dose this worked for you 